# How to display Two tables on a UI view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I would like to use and display two tables on a UI view. Please let me know how to do this. Any code same will also be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to just use "sections" instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Add 2 UITableViews to your view in IB and connect them to 2 different outlets in file owner (or simply assign different tag properties).
2. Set delegate and data source for them (may be same view controller for both).
3. In delegate/data source methods you do the following:

   ```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{    
       if (tableView == myFirstTable)
           // return value for 1st table
       if (tableView == mySecondTable)
           // return value for 2nd table
        return 0;
   }
   ```

or if you use tag approach:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{   
    switch(tableView.tag){
         case firstTag:
            // return value for 1st table
         case secondTag: 
            // return value for 2nd table
    }
    return 0;
}
```