# How to change properties of a TableView in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder

I m a total beginner in iOS development and need a bit of help:

I have a UIViewController with 2 nested TableViews. 
(Implementation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072340/how-to-display-two-tables-on-a-ui-view))

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabAboutViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *navigationList;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "TabAboutViewController.h"

@interface TabAboutViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabAboutViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Synthesize

@synthesize navigationList;
@synthesize informationTableView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Load

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    navigationList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Was leistet die App?",@"Wie wird gemessen?",@"Wie wird ausgewertet?",@"Was sind die Vorteile?",nil];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View UnLoad

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Rotates

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Management

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.navigationList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"aboutCell"];
    NSString *cellText = [self.navigationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Now i want to set the background Color for one of the TableViews in the UIViewController, but i dont know how and where to do it. i dont want to change it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
    // ...
}
```

And don't forget to add an `IBOutlet` to the table view in the .h file if you didn't already do that and link to it from Interface Builder:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

If you use tags to identify your views, you can do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UITableView *myTableView = [self.view viewWithTag:1]; // Or what ever tag you associate with the table view
    myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hm, i tested both both methodes... but the background color doesnt change

Comment: Are you sure you linked the table view to the IBOutlet or that you set the correct tag value? Also are you sure `myTableView` is not `nil` when you try to access it? Try adding `NSLog(@"myTableView: %@", myTableView);` at the end of `viewDidLoad `.

Comment: for testing purpose i deleted the second table, then i added (@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableView;) to the .h file, (@synthesize mytableView;) to the .m file and (
    self.mytableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];) to the viewDidLoad methode... the NSLog(@"myTableView: %@", myTableView); gives back "null"

Comment: ok, the answer above found my problem: i forgot to connect the outlet in the interfaceBuilder... as i said - i m totaly new to ios dev ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableview.backgroundcolor = [UIColor blueColor]; // change color here..


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    navigationList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Was leistet die App?",@"Wie wird gemessen?",@"Wie wird ausgewertet?",@"Was sind die Vorteile?",nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can define the backgroundcolor right within the nib file!

But if you want to do it code-based, then make sure you have connected the tableviews in interface builder to your corresponding IBOutlets in your .h file. Then you can access these tableviews in your code from any point you want (viewDidLoad or later).

Comment: omg, thank you - i have forgotton to connect the outlet in the interfacebuilder ;)